# TCP Server (Java) not receiving Packets from TCP Client (Python)

Tags: python, java, sockets

### Problem

I have a TCP Server (Java) that listens on port 55555. As soon as a client connects to it, it listens for a packet and if the packet is correct, opens a new socket and sends the new port to the client. I know that the server side code can work, because I have written a small java client that works fine with it, but my python client can only connect (when it sends a packet the server doesn't seem to react to it).

I hope somebody has an idea how to get this working and thanks in advance for your help!

### What else I have tried

1. appending "\n" "\r\n" to the python packet: same result
2. searching Stackoverflow, haven't found anything in over an hour

### Code

The Server

```java
// Server.java
private void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            ssocket = new ServerSocket(config.defaultPort);
            System.out.println("Socket opened on port "+config.defaultPort);
            Socket socket = ssocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection established");
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            String msg = dis.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Packet received");
            ssocket.close();
            if (msg.startsWith(config.specialChars.get("initConnectionServer").toString())) {
                System.out.println("Connection initiated by another server");
                // Connection was initiated by another server
                // parse message
                String[] parts = msg.substring(1).split(config.specialChars.get("listSeparator").toString());
                String name = parts[0];
                String passwd = parts[1];
                /// check name and password
                if (BCrypt.checkpw(passwd, config.ServerPW) && name.equals(config.ServerName)) {
                    System.out.println("Password and Name match our Server Network");
                    // add new server worker
                    ServerWorkerServer t = new ServerWorkerServer();
                    t.start();
                    workers.add(t);
                    // send new port
                    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    dos.writeUTF(""+config.specialChars.get("newPortResponse")+t.port);
                    dos.flush();
                    System.out.println("new port sent back: "+t.port);
                    socket.close();
                    ssocket.close();
                } else {
                    if (name.equals(config.ServerName)) {
                        System.out.println("Password does not match our server network");
                        System.out.println(passwd);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Name does not match our server network");
                        System.out.println(name);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Message is not valid");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

test client in java:

```java
// client.java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost",55555);
        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        dout.writeUTF("\uE001OG-ServerNet\uE000password");
        dout.flush();
        dout.close();
        s.close();
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
}
```

test client in python:

```py
# client.py
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("localhost", 55555))
s.send(b"\uE001OG-ServerNet\uE000password")
```

### Output

all output is from server.java upon connection by the respective client

client.java

```
Socket opened on port 55555
Connection established
Packet received
Connection initiated by another server
Password and Name match our Server Network
new port sent back: 29517
```

client.py

```
Socket opened on port 55555
Connection established
```

### Notes

`config.specialChars.get("initConnectionServer")` returns `\uE001`

`config.specialChars.get("listSeparator")` returns `\uE000`

`config.specialChars.get("newPortResponse")` returns `\uE002`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two statements do not transmit the same data:

```
 Java:   out.writeUTF("\uE001OG-ServerNet\uE000password");
 Python: s.send(b"\uE001OG-ServerNet\uE000password")
```

The Java statement interprets the given string as Unicode. It will convert the string to UTF-8 and will thus transmit the byte sequence:

```
 \xee\x80\x81OG-ServerNet\xee\x80\x80password
```

The Python statement instead interprets the given string as a byte sequence, because it was explicitly declared as such with the `b"..."` syntax. This means it will transmit the following byte sequence:

```
 \\uE001OG-ServerNet\\uE000password
```

To transmit the same thing as the Java code do not use `b"..."` but `"...".encode()`. This will interpret the string as Unicode and convert it to a UTF-8 byte sequence.

Comment: This was very enlightening, even though the "output" you have given for the java statement is not entirely correct. As I have found out due to an EOFException that the server produced, when using `s.send("...".encode("utf-8"))`,  the `readUTF()` Method expects the length of the message to be encoded in the first two bytes, so the correct "output" is actually `\x00\x1a\xee\x80\x81OG-ServerNet\xee\x80\x80password`

Comment: @JannStute: thanks for the feedback., Interestingly I find these two bytes length [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF-java.lang.String-) as output for the writeUTF method, but not as expected input for the [readUTF](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readUTF-java.io.DataInput-) method

Comment: Yeah I found that out the hard way by searching for the cause of an EOFError that occured when sending the "correctly" formatted data, just for me to setup a python server and find those bytes in the beginning smh